# XMLHttpRequestのresponseTypeが、IE以外のブラウザの場合動かない

Tags: javascript

IEでは問題なく動き、画像が表示されます。
しかし、IE以外のブラウザ（Firefox、Safari）で動かした場合、「request.responseType="arraybuffer";」の部分で止まり、それ以降の文は動きません。
この部分をコメントアウトすれば、動きはする様になります。

Firefoxの場合、openの後にresponseTypeを指定しなければならないという話も出てきましたが、それでも動かない様です。
何が問題なのでしょうか。

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function(){
  if(request.status==200){
    var blob=new Blob([request.response],{type:'image/gif'});
    document.getElementById('img').src=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  }
};
request.open('GET',picture_name,false);
request.responseType="arraybuffer";
request.send();
```

Comment: `request.responseType="blob";`で初めからBlobを取得してはどうでしょうか？

Comment: 「request.open('GET',picture_name,false);」 を 「request.open('GET',picture_name,true);」 に変更した所、Firefox、Safari共に動く様になりました。 有難う御座いました。

Answer (score 2):

Firefox11より同期リクエスト(`request.open`の3つめの引数がfalseのリクエスト)でresponseTypeを使用するとエラーになるようになったそうです。

> 同期リクエストの実行時における、XMLHttpRequest responseType および withCredentials 属性の使用のサポートを削除しました。属性の使用を試みると、NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_ACCESS_ERR 例外が発生します。この変更は、W3C へ標準化の提案が行われました。

[Firefox 11 for developers - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/Firefox/Releases/11)

`request.open`の3つ目の引数をtrueに変更してみてください。

Comment: 「request.open('GET',picture_name,false);」
を
「request.open('GET',picture_name,true);」
に変更した所、Firefox、Safari共に動く様になりました。
有難う御座いました。